# How to Send SOAP Header with XMLDP from SSRS XML DataService

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, reporting-services

I'm trying to use a vendor's web service via the XML Data Source within SSRS (2008R2.)
I've nearly solved it all with the exception that the vendor's web service requires a soap header with a client identification block.

I've found no way in the documentation to send a soap header via the XMLDP query langauge.

I'v been watching the actual soap sent by the XML Data source with Fiddler and it actually looks like it omits the SOAP Header Entirely.

Main question: Is this even possible?

The Microsoft documentation I've found omits mention of SOAP headers, and other non-authoritative sources indicate that I need to create my own Custom Data Extension and deploy this to the SSRS Server.

Creating a new CDE and deploying to the server is beyond scope for this project.

Thanks,

PS: I'm using the  method of calling the web service in-case that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution ended up being:
Create a new pass-through web-service I could call which in-turn called the vendor web-service.  Since this will be short lived solution the small amount of pain created by the extra step is acceptable.

To be sure, there was no found way to use the XMLDP to send the required SOAP header.